# How to undo 'Undo Retweet'?

Tags: twitter

I had retweeted something about a week ago and just now accidently clicked 'Undo Retweet' when trying to see who else had retweeted it.

Is it possible to undo an 'Undo Retweet'?

I know I could just re-retweet it now but I don't want to do that because it had date-specific content and it'd look weird retweeting something about a past 'upcoming' event. I just want to reinstate it as if I had never undone the retweet.

There was no info about this on the Twitter ['FAQs about Retweets' page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/77606-faqs-about-retweets-rt#).

Answer (score 3):

Undoing an Undo retweet is... simply retweet. So the only way to undo that is to retweet again.